# mp3 sorting: copy one column accordingly to another file

Tags: bash, text, tags, mp3

Basically here is what i want to do:
I have unsorted mp3 files that do not have track numbers. I downloaded the complete txt file (the file contains the album's track's numbers, artists and titles in the order 1 - someone - something). My next step was to import all the file names from the album folder to another txt.

So here is an example of the first txt:

```
1 - CCC - C
2 - AAA - A
3 - BBB - B
```

And here is my generated txt file:

```
AAA - A
BBB - B
CCC - C
```

Can someone please post a full command or a script so i could get an output file like this:

```
2 - AAA - A
3 - BBB - B
1 - CCC - C
```

For the record it's not a school assignment. I like my mp3s sorted and there are just too many unsorted albums and using mp3tag or anything else to manual search for the files and type in the numbers is too much time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -t - -k 2 first.txt
```

Output:

```
2 - AAA - A
3 - BBB - B
1 - CCC - C
```